# How terasort works

Tags: hadoop, terasort

I tried to use hadoop terasort, and it worked well with teragen and teravalid.
Then I wondered how the terasort works. I thought terasort works like a `sort` command in linux. So I made a text file like below:

```
I have a pen.
my name is ~
I went to my lab yesterday
...
```

Then ran the terasort but error "read past eof" is returned.

I saw "part-m-00000" which is generated by teragen, but couldn't understand.

Please tell me how the terasort is working.

Comment: From a cursory glance at the documentation, terasort requires a 1TB file ("tera-" in the name). Your file was too small.

Comment: The input file doesn't have to be a terabyte. When running Teragen you can specify the number of 100 byte rows to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terasort doesn't require a terabyte of input data but it does assume that the data is in the format produced by [Teragen](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/TeraGen.html). More specifically:

- (10 bytes key) (10 bytes rowid) (78 bytes filler) \r \n
- The keys are random characters from the set ' ' .. '~'.
- The rowid is the right justified row id as a int.
- The filler consists of 7 runs of 10 characters from 'A' to 'Z'.

Answer (score 1):

EOF means the file was consumed entirely before it could read 1 **tera**byte of (randomly distributed) data

Therefore it exited before trying to sort anything